# date difference in week and days in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have to display duration between startdate and EndDate
for that i am use **DATEDIFF** of week it will give me a int value like 3 week , 2 week 
but DATEDIFF of days is 23 then result like **3 Week, 2 days**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) as WeekCount,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 7 as DayCount
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36') AS days;
```

to get the days and then just divide by 7 to get the weeks, and % to get the days

Comment: i dont want difference in days i want ta result like **3 Week 2 Days**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

**Mysql**

```
SELECT concat(floor(DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36')/7)," Weeks ",mod(DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36'),7)," Days");
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT concat(floor(DATEDIFF(day, '2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36')/7)," Weeks ",mod(DATEDIFF(day, '2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36'),7)," Days");
```

Result is `2 Weeks 3 Days`

Though i am sure there is a better way to do the differences in one go rather than do `DATEDIFF` twice.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Hello Nikos Can you please tell me vesion of SQL server , because of DATEDIFF required 3 argument but in your example it's 2 argument

Comment: Hi @Chirag, apologies for keeping you waiting. I have edited my answer. My original reply was for MySQL. I have added the SQL Server equivallent.

Comment: SELECT concat(floor(DATEDIFF(day, '2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2011-09-21 21:40:36')/7),' Weeks ',(DATEDIFF(day, '2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2011-09-21 21:40:36') % 7),' Days');